# How can I get a JWT Access Token using Docusign 4.0.4.0

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

I have a legacy application written in VB6 (I Know!!) to which I am adding a DocuSign feature. I a using InterOp to run .NET code written is VS2019 VB.Net. The reason I am using 4.0.4.0 as this is the version I can successfully call using InterOp. I have all the code working except for requesting a JWT token. Does anyone have JWT code working under this version of the API ?

This is what I have working under later versions of DocuSign and am trying to replace
`Dim privatekey As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("docusign_private_key.key")
Dim result As Object = x.RequestJWTApplicationToken(gsSIGNERCLIENTID, docuSignAuthServer, privatekey, 1, scopes)

```
    txtAccessToken.Text = result



   

    '
    '   Second attempt at alternative
    '
  `  Dim authToken As OAuth.OAuthToken = x.RequestJWTUserToken(gsSIGNERCLIENTID, gsUserIDGUID, docuSignAuthServer, privatekey, 1)
    txtAccessToken.Text = authToken.access_token`

    '
    '   Third attempt
    '
    Dim request = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.Headers.Add("username", "user123")
    request.Headers.Add("password", "123")
    request.Headers.Add("auth_access_type", "read")
    request.ContentLength = 0
    Dim responseContent As String = ""
    Using response = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Using


    '
    '   Fifth attempt
    '
    Dim apiClient5 As New ApiClient(gsBASEPATH)
    Dim authToken5 As OAuth.OAuthToken = apiClient5.RequestJWTUserToken(gsINTEGRATIONKEY, gsUserIDGUID, "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token", privatekey, 1, scopes)
```

All results in 'Error while requesting server, received a non-successful HTPC code Error with response Body'

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is correct:

```
Dim authToken As OAuth.OAuthToken = x.RequestJWTUserToken(gsSIGNERCLIENTID, gsUserIDGUID, docuSignAuthServer, privatekey, 1)
    txtAccessToken.Text = authToken.access_token
```

`AuthServer` has to be "account-d.docusign.com"
The `privateKey` has to be the exact thing you got from DocuSign, including the new lines and all. To get it use this code:

`File.ReadAllBytes(path)` where path is the `path` on the disk to a plain text file with your private key.

gsSIGNERCLIENTID should be the GUID for the user that you use that has consent. You must make sure user gave consent by building a consent URL as explained in here:

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/

If you did all of this correctly - it should work.

Comment: It's working thanks. Removing the https:// from account-d.docusign.com helped

Comment: yes, exactly, it's not a full URL, just a domain name